# Run Kafka Streams ProcesssorContext `schedule()` at fixed times

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is is possible to configure, or implement logic, for the [ProcessorContext schedule()](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html#schedule(java.time.Duration,org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.PunctuationType,org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Punctuator)) to run at fixed times? For instance, like a cron job every ten seconds?

I have seen [KAFKA-7699](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7699), but it looks to be stale?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.  The best you could do with the [schedule(interval, type, callback)](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/api/ProcessingContext.html#schedule-java.time.Duration-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.PunctuationType-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Punctuator-) method would be to estimate how often you'd like the callback to execute via the `Duration` interval parameter and choose `PuctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME`.  Note using `WALL_CLOCK_TIME` is best effort only "as its granularity is limited by how long an iteration of the processing loop takes to complete"